# OpenShift v3 deploy a springboot binary jar

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am looking for ways to deploy a springboot binary jar on OpenShift v3.  I can do it with Yaml and have done it on Kubernetes but I am looking for specifically deploying a jar directly on OpenShift v3.  I have looked here [OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#binary-source) but can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this post :https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/03/deploy-spring-boot-applications-openshift/
Using s2i image.Google luck.

Answer (score 1):

Another good post to try: https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-enterprise-grade-spring-boot-deployments/

Repository url: 
https://github.com/jorgemoralespou/osev3-examples/tree/master/spring-boot/springboot-sti

Image and template works fine with recent version of origin.